# Excel 2010 - Take whole rows from one sheet and display them in the 2nd sheet based on match in 3rd sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'll cut to the chase:

Excel 2010

I have `Sheet1` with a list of orders. Customer name is in column `F`.

`Sheet2` contains list of customers with just their names in column `A`.

I would like to run a macro / vlookup / index (whatever works) to run through the list of thousands of orders in `Sheet1` and copy to `Sheet3` the rows (whole rows) where the customer name from `Sheet2` matches.

`Sheet1` has 10 columns and about 10000 rows. 
`Sheet2` has about 50 rows in column A only.

I have tried a few types of macros and did a proper search but couldn't find anything that would work. I would paste what I have but that would only be an embarrassment.

I might add that I will need to run this weekly and the list of orders will be changing. List of names may too but with little frequency.

Can you help? :)

**EDIT**: From the answers so far I can see that I would need to use VBA script. I would appreciate help with that as I know next to nothing about the language. I should be able to manage modifying the script to suit my needs but I need something to start. Perhaps this pseudocode will make it easier for you good people:

---

*Read data from A1:A50 in Sheet2*

*Compare F1, Sheet1 with A1:A50, Sheet2*

*If no match - continue to F2*

*If match - copy whole row to A1 in Sheet3*

(...)

*Compare Fx, Sheet1 with A1:A50, Sheet2*

*If no match - continue to Fx+1*

*If match - copy whole row to A(n+1) [n=number of matches] in Sheet3*

*Continue comparing rows in Sheet1 to A1:A50, Sheet2 and return next match in An, Sheet3*

---

So far I have something like this but the problem is that it returns data to Sheet3 *only* if row number in Sheet2 matches row number in Sheet1. Also, it returns it to Sheet3, row number matching Sheet1. So I end up with one result in row 45 in Sheet3 instead of around 20 results in rows 1-20.

```
Sub asd()
For Counter = 1 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Sheets(1).Range("F" & Counter).Value = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Counter).Value Then
      Sheets(3).Range("C" & (Counter)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Counter).Value
      Sheets(3).Range("D" & (Counter)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("B" & Counter).Value
    End If
Next Counter
End Sub
```

Thank you,
Pat

Comment: Create a copy of  Sheet1 and name it "Orders". In a new column (Column 11) on the "Orders" sheet , use the match formula to see when column F matches column A in sheet2.  Then filter the "Orders" sheet and delete all of the #NA's in your data and you are done.

Comment: Thanks rwilson for your reply. I have a feeling though that it won't be as straightforward as I hope it to be for repeated, weekly use. Especially given that I want to share the method / macro for use by my colleagues. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm just giving you the steps you can take in Excel to complete the process. Using these steps, the macro recorder, and a little work, you should be able to do this. Nobody on SO knows your data better than you do.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you'll need to use VBA script to copy the entire row.

Please make sure your data in both sheets 1 & 2 is sorted if you wish to use vlookup, but I don't think it will help since vlookup will "stop" on the first hit, meaning if you have a customer names John on sheet1 which repeats several times, vlookup will only pick the first occurrence

Regards,